# Running Windows CE applications on a Windows Mobile 6.1-.5 device

Tags: emulator, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6, pda

In my duties at the office i'm managing a PDA solution ran on a Windows CE-PDA. However, we'd like to migrate this software to a Windows Mobile 6.1-.5 equivalent. Is there any kind of compability software/emulator/other technique that might help me achieve this?

Brgds,
Simon

Comment: I am not aware of any Windows CE emulator on Windows Mobile 6.x considering Windows Mobile 6.x is not being supported.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! However, considering the period during which mobile 6 was actually supported, I was hoping to find some kind of legacy software which could still be of use. Sadly, in some situations, we're still limited to using legacy os's since most rugged PDAs at a reasonable price still use this technology.

Comment: There are rugged Windows Phone 8 phone cases but thats about it.  As I indicated I am unware of anything that would fit what you describe.